# Google Sheets: Counts by Date

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to write a google sheet for a food pantry.  I need to count the bar codes for each item after the last inventory check.  That way if new inventory comes in, the Quantity on Hand can be changed and the Current Quantity as of Inv Date will not subtract items already given out.  I have tried Countifs and Query several different ways but I can't seem to make it work.  Here is my inventory sheet:

[image]

Here is the data from the Google Form:

[image]

```
=if(COUNTIFS(Participation!$A$1:$A$10004, ">" & B2),(C2-COUNTIFS(Participation!$B$2:$G$10004,D2)),C2)
```

This works but it adds all data on the table if the first condition is met.

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result.

Comment: In addition to providing sample sheet, it is important for you to define your input and desired output precisely and clearly. What exactly are you trying to count? Where is the data location? e.g. Just Column C to G in `Participation!`? If not, how is the number of columns determined? What is the data you are trying to extract? You hinted at matching bar code number, make it explicit. Are there also other requirements? e.g. Is there a date cut off. Please do *not* ask a real life problem to be solved by others on Stack Overflow. Ask specific programming questions *only*.

Comment: My apologies...first time asking anything on this forum.  I uploaded a sample spreadsheet (Pantry_Sample).  Basically, I need cell Inventory!E2 to show a count of all the barcodes scanned from the Participation! that match Inventory!D2 --AFTER--the last inventory check date which is tab Inventory!B2.  That way, if someone manually counts each item, they can update the Last Inventory Date column and Beginning Quantity column and the previous entries on Participation will not be counted in Current Quantity.  

My E2 IF with Countifs works but is wrong if updated it still counts previous scans.

Comment: `uploaded a sample spreadsheet` Where, the link?

Comment: Sorry.  I thought it auto added it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pv4Z9K2HvPMEFWBZ004WHXEHD7JoxoICLVduRwlQajA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me.  However,  I would only like to count the matching in rows that have dates that are after the updates.  Would query be a better choice?

Comment: FYI: COUNTIFS(Participation!$A$1:$A$10004, ">" & B2) ->adds all data on the table if the first condition is met. The reason for this is the date value on "Inventory" has an underlying value as at the 8start* of the day: "5 Feb 2024" => 2/5/2024 0:00:00. OTOH, Timestamps on "Participation" reflect submissions during the day. So, all of the entries on "Participation" are greater than the date on "Inventory". One solution is use a criteria of ">="&(B2+1)) - i.e., add 24 hours to the Inventory date, and evaluate for dates "greater than or equal to the modified Inventory date"

Comment: `Would query be a better choice?` That's what I've been working on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in cell E2, and copy down as many rows as required:

`=C2-iferror(ArrayFormula(query(query({split(flatten(Participation!$A$2:$A&"x"&Participation!$B$2:$B&"x"&"'"&Participation!$C$2:$G),"x")},"select Col1, Col2, Col3  where Col1 is not null and Col3 is not null format Col1 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss'"),"select count(Col3) where Col3 = '"&D2&"' and  toDate(Col1)>date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label count(Col3) ''")),0)`

---

**Inventory**

[image: inventory]

---

**Analysis**

[image: analysis]

---

**Logic**

- The basis of the answer is a `QUERY` to consolidate barcode readings

  - each reading consists of between one and five products (barcodes)
  - in order to assist with analysis, these are flattened to create an array of one barcode per row
  - for information ONLY, the output is shown on sheet = `analysis`

h/t:  @player0 for  [How can I use Query() and Flatten() in Google Sheets to reference a variable amount of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72114859/1330560)

Comment: Thank you, Tedinoz!  I greatly appreciate the help.  This code works flawlessly.  I will try to break it down and learn from this.  There are several parts of your formula that I have never considered trying.

Comment: I wasn't happy that I couldn't provide a single formula that wouldn't require copying. It's possible that one of the `LAMBDA` options would do the trick, but I decided that it was better to provide an "imperfect answer" rather than "no answer at all" :)